# Does any body using qtest and postgres with SSL enabled for postgres?

Tags: postgresql, qtest

qTest: 11.3.0
Elasticsearch: 7.7.1
PostgreSQL: 13.12.1

We are having issues adding the SSL certificate to PostgreSQL. After adding the SSL cert files and when we try to install qtest. we are getting the below error.

Existing properties not available, use project properties
[23-12-05 11:17:47] org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The hostname [xxxxx] could not be verified by hostnameverifier PgjdbcHostnameVerifier.
at org.postgresql.ssl.MakeSSL.verifyPeerName(MakeSSL.java:81)
at org.postgresql.ssl.MakeSSL.convert(MakeSSL.java:52)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.enableSSL(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:584)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:168)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:235)
at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.(PgConnection.java:247)
at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:434)

Answer (score 0):

Your server certificate is bad. You need to use a certificate whose common name is the host name that you specified on the client side.